# Error checking wrapper c++

Tags: c++, error-handling, wrapper

I would like to write a wrapper for some functions to check their return values or some parameter for errors, so I don't need to write `if`s everytime I call something. Also I want this wrapper to be called only when in debug mode.

I want something like this:

```
CheckError(myfunction(myParam1, myParam2, ...);
```

where `myFunction` returns some error code or for example `myParam2` return this code by reference.

I've managed to write solution for first case using preprocessor macro:

```
#define CHECK_RESULT(function) \
{\
    if(function != VNT_SUCCESS)\
    { \
        std::cout << "ERROR!\n"; \
    }\
}
```

But I kinda don't like using preprocessor macro for this. I've read something about using perfect forwarding for this, also seen some solutions to my problem, but they all required to create templated wrapper which would require me to separate function name and params and not just wrap function call as is (see above).

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may do regular function instead of MACRO:

```
void CheckError(const EStatus& res) // Reference to allow your second check
{
#ifdef DEBUG // Choose appropriate flag according to your build option
    if (res != VNT_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR!\n";
    }
#endif
}
```

and use it:

```
CheckError(myfunction(myParam1, myParam2));
CheckError((myfunction2(myParam1, myParam2), myParam2)); // To check myParam2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define ENUMNAME EValDebug
#else
#define ENUMNAME EStatus
#endif

enum ENUMNAME {E_OK, ...}

#ifdef DEBUG
class EStatus {
  EStatus(ENUMNAME e) {
    switch (e) {}
  }
}
#endif
```